# Xamarin Forms: Grid button UI breaks when click restart button

Tags: user-interface, button, xamarin.forms, grid

I am using a `button` inside the `grid` for showing letters to implement a `Word search game`. Initially, the UI is looking good, but when clicks the `play again` button the UI breaks.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Code for the setting button inside grid:**

```
void SetGridLayout(char[,] matrixToPrint)
{
    int numRows = matrixToPrint.GetLength(0);
    int numCols = matrixToPrint.GetLength(1);

    gridLayout.HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand;
    gridLayout.SetBinding(Button.HeightRequestProperty, new Binding("Width", source: gridLayout));

    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; row++)
    {
        gridLayout.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
    }
    for (int col = 0; col < numCols; col++)
    {
        gridLayout.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition { Width = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Star) });
    }

    for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < numRows; rowIndex++)
    {
        for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < numCols; columnIndex++)
        {
            var Rowbutton = new Button
            {
                Text = Char.ToString(matrixToPrint[rowIndex, columnIndex]),
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand,
                Padding = 0,
                Margin = 0,
                BackgroundColor = Color.White
            };
            Rowbutton.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, "ClickCommand");
            Rowbutton.SetValue(Button.CommandParameterProperty, new PassObject(Rowbutton, rowIndex.ToString() + "," + columnIndex.ToString()));
            Rowbutton.SetBinding(Button.HeightRequestProperty, new Binding("Width", source: Rowbutton));
            gridLayout.Children.Add(Rowbutton, columnIndex, rowIndex);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried a lot to find the cause behind this issue, but no luck. I have uploaded a sample project [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1farJceizDyaree7Zo47TkfJ6bbmZTjz-/view?usp=sharing) for the reference. Thanks in advance.

Comment: at a glance, it appears that you are adding new rows and cols to an existing Grid without clearing it first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are adding new rows and cols to an existing `Grid` without clearing it first